# Delete message in Mail using Applescript doesn't propagate to iCloud

Tags: macos, email, applescript, icloud

I have an `Applescript` that performs a lookup when a new mail lands in my `Mail` inbox to check whether I have blacklisted the e-mail's domain or not.

If the e-mail domain is blacklisted, the script deletes the mail by doing so:

```
tell application "Mail"
  delete blackListedMailMessage
end tell
```

Pretty straightforward.  My e-mails are properly filtered according to this blacklist of mine and moved to my trash mailbox, as I expect them to be.

The problem comes when I click the "Get messages" button in Mail: Mail retrieves the deleted messages from the server and put them back in my inbox.  It seems the deletion doesn't propagate to the server.  If I manually select the e-mail in Mail.app and hit delete, this does not happen.

I'm pretty newb with Applescript, so I'm not sure what's all going on.  My guesses are either the Mail.app's Applescript implementation is janky or it's iCloud.  It could be both...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I'll answer my own question...

It seems that Apple's implementation of Mail.app's Applescript `delete` is bugged.

Instead, use:

```
tell application "Mail"
  move aMessage to trash mailbox
end tell
```

Otherwise, it will not propagate to the server if using iCloud.